# Wifi is disabled by hardware switch

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I installed fresh copy of ubunti 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu use my entire disk but i cannot connect to wifi i see enable wifi button is in grey color

```
rfkill list all
```

shows

```
phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked : no
      Hard blocked : yes
```

I tried

```
rfkill unblock all
```

but problem remain same

i also did

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

Both Network Controller and Ethernet Controller uses kernel driver so i think it might not be a driver problem ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @GAD3R: That question is about a *soft-blocked* wireless adapter.